# What is the cast time of a metamagic'd swift action spell for a spontaneous caster?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, metamagic

I have a sorcerer that wishes to [Cold Ice Strike](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Cold%20Ice%20Strike) in a game. I don't mind this, but the issue is they want to apply Empower spell via a metamagic rod to it. Normally with a standard action spell this becomes a full-round action, but Cold Ice Strike is a swift action spell, and I can't find anything for that.

If the sorcerer casts Empowered Cold Ice Strike, what's the casting time of it?

Comment: I can't believe that my search didn't bring that up.

Comment: that's okay! Duplicates are a good thing. Next time someone has this issue, now they are more likely to find it in search.